# kafka zookeeper distributed setup using private ips

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have setup kafka zookeeper distributed setup using 3 machines already and using inbuilt zookeeper of kafka only. I want to setup private ips for this system now.

I have set `host.name=private_ip` in `server.properties`, After setting this my kafka server is running on private ips.

But not getting idea how to setup private ip for zookeeper. Do I need to set something in `zookeeper.properties` ?

or is there any other setting for this ?

Answer (score 0):

The zookeeper shipped with Kafka is used for single node zk set up. It's better if you use zookeeper software for multi-node set up. You can set up private ips to server.1, server.2 and server.3 in zoo.cfg. You can follow this [link](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_zkMulitServerSetup) for multi-node zookeeper setup.

Hope This Helps